# WinSCP automate file transfer- Should the batch and script file locate in virtual or local directory?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, sftp, file-transfer, winscp

I'm trying to import a CSV file from my local machine to virtual machine (`ABC FTP`).

Should both of my batch & text file be located in `C:\test\Test.txt`? which is a virtual machine directory?
And having the WinSCP running on local directory (connected to `ABC FTP`), by double-clicking the batch file on virtual machine, do I trigger WinSCP to import my CSV file from `C:\Transfer\ToABCTest\`?

My batch file (`.bat`) is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\winSCP\winSCP.com" /script="C:\test\Test.txt"
```

My text file (`.txt`) is:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ABCFTP
lcd C:\Transfer\ToABCTest\
get -delete  /test_edi_in/*.txt
close
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Store the scripts wherever you want, as long as the local machine has an access to them.

---

Though if the local machine has a direct access to the virtual machine folder, it seems like an overkill to use WinSCP/FTP to download files.

So chances are, that I do not understand your question.